# Matplotlib graph adjusment with big dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a big dataset of 83000 rows with dates and values. I want to generate a plot with a moving average value and time. But my graph is not clear as you may see in the images. How can I adjust the graph and make it clearer? Is there another way to plot such a big dataset like this? When I look at this graph so many lines are like put on each other and they don't mean a lot?

(I generally use matplotlib and seaborn libraries for Python)
[image: you may see an example graph here]

Comment: Is this a programming question? What do you think the output should look like?

Comment: I think you may explain further what do you mean by `clear`. You can give an example of clear image. Or people may not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this dataframe:

```
df.head()
   complete    mid_c    mid_h    mid_l    mid_o                      time 
0      True  0.80936  0.80943  0.80936  0.80943 2018-01-31 09:54:10+00:00   
1      True  0.80942  0.80942  0.80937  0.80937 2018-01-31 09:54:20+00:00   
2      True  0.80946  0.80946  0.80946  0.80946 2018-01-31 09:54:25+00:00   
3      True  0.80942  0.80942  0.80940  0.80940 2018-01-31 09:54:30+00:00   
4      True  0.80944  0.80944  0.80944  0.80944 2018-01-31 09:54:35+00:00
```

Create a 50 moving average:

```
df['ma'] = df.mid_c.rolling(window=50).mean()
```

plot it:

```
df.plot('time', ['mid_c', 'ma'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.show()
```

[image]